# Can I get 'Clone Source' values with a script in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Is it possible to get values of this panel with a script in Photoshop? I tried to use xbytor's `Getter.jsx` but it didn't register any changes in these fields.

[image]

Comment: Well it seems scripting listener catching source points!I tried taking 3x alternate source points and all time it catched it; you wanna get x,y coordinates right?

Comment: true, but I can't find where it goes afterwards: there's no `ClnS` char ID in tools or applications :/ I want to get all the properties: source scale, rotation, flip

Comment: yeah that's true :/ it don't catches result points